# Labview change properties of control by code

Tags: labview

How could I change max and min values in control "fill slide" by code?

Here is my program and it should take max and min values from CSV file and change scale range in fill slide's properties. How could i get access to fill slide's properties?

---

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eFfQuRzPgASHQtNTY0LVpmY0k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the diagram, right click on the control and create a property node.  Select the Data Entry Limits property, min and max can be set. The property node must be writable to set properties.

Answer (score 0):

after creating property node, right click on it, choose Properties, Scale, Range, and Minimum (or Maximum) to set the visible data range for the fill slide. Let me know if you need more help.